# How to perform a search in a Multivalued Field in Solr?

Tags: search, solr, multivalue

I'm having dificulties to execute a search in Solr. My Solr has a Multivalued field like this document below:

```
<int name="id">2166324592435</int>
...others fields
<arr name="Series">
   <str>The Walking Dead<\str>
   <str>Game of Thrones<\str>
<\arr>
```

The Multivalued field Series has the Tv serie which the document references. In the example above, my document says about The Walking Dead and Game of Thrones. I can have documents with one, two or more series or even no series.

What I want to do is search in Solr. I want to give the series that I want and Solr should returns the documents that says about my query. I tryed but I couldn't do it. I tryed the following:

```
q=series:The Walking Dead or series:Game of Thrones or ...&wt=json
```

I think I'm doing wrong. What's the correctly way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Thiago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @user1452132 's answer -

When you are searching `q=series:The Walking Dead`, only `the` is searched across the series field while the `walking dead` is search across the default search field.

The query formed would be series:the OR text:(Walking Dead)

You can debug the Query using the debugQuery=on in your request url.

You can use [Dismax query handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxRequestHandler) to make it more manageable.

Answer (score 9):

Try something like this:
 `series:("The Walking Dead" OR "Game of Thrones")`

Comment: When use as `filter query` parameter, this actually works.

Answer (score 2):

Use in `fq` parameter (filter query),

### E.g

```
    name:("Java" OR "Python")
    name:("Java" AND "Web")

    // multivalued fields
    author_ids:(1733 OR 58)
    author_ids:(1733 AND 58)
```

### Solr url encoding:

- ':' become '%3A'
- space become '+'

### Thus, you might get a url like this:

> http://localhost:8983/solr/xxx/select?q=programming&fq=title%3A("Java"+AND+"web")&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&qf=title&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the intent of the search is try the following two searches

series:"The Walking Dead" OR series:"Game of Thorns"

series:(The Walking Dead) OR series:(Game of Thorns)

Please read [solr query syntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) and the underlying [Lucene query syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think your the actual problem is using `OR` as lowercase. When you do something like that, The `or` value is searched in `defaultTextField`. Also don't forget to put quotes if there's a whitespace in your query - and you're looking for an exact match.